# why Angular component selector can be included in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm new to Angular and html/html5, sorry if my questions sound dumb. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

My questions are:

Q1- `paproductform` is ng component selector's name, which is not a valid html tag, how come it can still be included in html?How client browsers interpret those invalid tags?

Q2- You can see that there are a lots of ng related attributes like `_nghost-c0`, isn't that custom attributes in html has to be data-xxx(data-_nghost-c0) to be valid?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular Documentation:](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

> Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements (also called Web Components), a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way. 
>  
>  Custom elements are a Web Platform feature currently supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari, and available in other browsers through polyfills (see Browser Support). A custom element extends HTML by allowing you to define a tag whose content is created and controlled by JavaScript code. The browser maintains a **CustomElementRegistry** of defined custom elements, which maps an instantiable JavaScript class to an HTML tag.

**A1 - Creating custom HTML Elements using [CustomElementRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define).**

use the `CustomElementRegistry.define()` method to define the custom element after creating its class:

```js
class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {

    super(); 

    var wcParent = this.parentNode;   // count words in element's parent element

    function countWords(node){
      var text = node.innerText || node.textContent
      return text.split(/\s+/g).length;
    }

    var count = 'Words: ' + countWords(wcParent);

    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});  // Create a shadow root

    // Create text node and add word count to it
    var text = document.createElement('span');
    text.textContent = count;

    shadow.appendChild(text);  // Append it to the shadow root

    setInterval(function() {  // Update count when element content changes
      var count = 'Words: ' + countWords(wcParent);
      text.textContent = count;
    }, 200)

  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('word-count', WordCount, { extends: 'p' });
```

**A2 - Creating custom attribue using [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).**

In the following example, `setAttribute()` is used to set attributes on a `<button>`.

**HTML**

```html
<button>Hello World</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var b = document.querySelector("button"); 

b.setAttribute("name", "helloButton");
b.setAttribute("disabled", "");
```